# DB query result to custom object

Tags: arrays, database, node.js, oop, orm

Right now I have started to develop my small project, just to extend my knowledge of some web-app aspects and to realise an idea I got last Monday. So, I've got NodeJS + Mongo. As project is for fun&education I don't care about performance etc, just to try something new.

Mowing to problem:
I've got some structured data, which was stored as a plain text file. After some dancing around I wrote a script, which convert those datas to Objects (custom Objects) and pushed them to MongoDB. But the problem is: after I get them from the DB - they are just plain objects. So I'm lacking of my sweet and great setters, getters etc.
After thinking for a while I found only one possibility, how to do it: run through the whole response array, and add to .prototype functionality I need (setters, getters, etc). But it seems to have very poor performance and approach seems to be silly.

I would ask you, what would be the right way to do so? For example when I use google APIs - I got custom objects, with bunch of a useful methods.
Other example - during the summer I was working on the project based on Symfony2, where I've used completely strange (in that moment) Doctrine2 ORM layer. In the OOP world I found it is awesome. They do the same trick under the hood - convert query result to Objects and returns them in array.

As I am not a guy, who asks for a magic pill, I ask you for some knowledge where to look, and what to look for, as I am completely lost right now?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not lost,  prob you are using  nodejs mongo driver,  a low level layer,  thats why responses are just js objects,  it is not a high level data layer like mongoose odm, you can parse data returned from the driver to do what you want. Doctrine is a orm ,  under the hood it uses a driver.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I am using mongo native driver. Please correct me, if I get it wrong, but whole magic of transforming results to objects in Symfony is hidden in the driver?

Comment: No ,  all that magic is done inside doctrine,  driver is a conector.

Comment: the driver is a conector that link to a DBSM , like mysql php driver http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php

Comment: So digging into Doctrine is the only way to learn that magic, or there are other sources I can learn patterns?

Comment: if you want a high level abstraction using mongo , you could check mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/) ,if you want to learn design patterns, you could read P of EAA (http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) where i found frameworks patterns explained.